# ActiveX in IE - disabling it outside the browser?

Tags: internet-explorer, activex

I'm using ActiveX to create textfiles:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); 
var fh = fso.CreateTextFile(...
```

I know that the user needs to click ok in a popup in order to allow the textfile to be created. But is there a guarantee that an activex control can be used as long as the user accepts it in IE, or is there any other settings that might prevent it (in windows)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be blocked by a firewall or ant-virus product.

ActiveX in the browser is a well known security issue. The example you've given is exactly the kind of thing that a decent anti-virus product should pick up and strip out of the code before it even reaches the browser.